# Help with restoring expired domain as quick as possible

Tags: domain, domain-name, expired

My domain name expired today (owing to missing credit card info, etc) and it is really important as the company has about 50 users who cannot access emails, website unreachable, etc. I have requested UKReg to bring the domains backup and running but they will take about 24 hours to get it back up and running.

Is there anything that I can do to return the service back to normal quicker?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer no.

The better registrars can usually get a domain back up in < 4 hours, but I don't have any UK suggestions for you (we run our own registrar for .uk domains)

Comment: This happened to my brother-in-law's company the other week.  It took about 4 hours to fix completely

Answer (score 1):

You are stuck with how ever long it takes your register to return it to you. Expect a hefty fee as well since it was in redemption.

Answer (score 1):

No. You're at the mercy of UKReg. Not to hit you when you're down, but why did you wait until the last minute to renew the domain name? I always give myself 2 to 4 weeks advance notice (Outlook reminder) so that I can work out any issues, like missing credit cards, etc.